# MySQL & PHP: When to establish connection with the MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When issuing a MySQL/SQL query from PHP code, a connection with the database must be firstly established.

Would you advise me, please, whether **I should establish connection with the database only at the beginning of the user's web session, or upon loading new page, or before every single MySQL/SQL query?**

I think that when establishing connection with the database too many times unnecessarily, I will consume unnecessary system resources. I would therefore prefer connecting with the database the minimum necessary times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to strike the right balance. Each part has its problems. Let's go over all three possibilities

**Persistent MySQL connection**

Advantages: load-once-and-forget

Disadvantages: you'll need to make sure to kill any connection that is not active anymore yourself. Also, a dormant connection still uses some resources. Not recommended, as the only good case for it is a lot of requests, at which point you'll most likely want to cluster up your database servers, and persistent connections tend to play havoc with that.

**One-query-one-request model**

Advantages: build-and-forget

Disadvantages: extreme resource usage.

The good solution is a right balance. Load up your DBH when you actually need it for the first time, and keep it until your script is over, at which point you should free all resources used by it and terminate it. This guarantees that you'll have done everything using the minimum amount of resources needed.

Comment: Except that you can't really establish truly permanent connection from PHP. Persistent connection is your only bet

Comment: About to edit my answer to rephrase this point exactly. By permanent, I was hinting at persistent.

Comment: @user1800246, +1, hi and thanks for this answer. It is logical and makes sense. You mentioned in your answer that there are three possibilities *"Let's go over all three possibilities"*. Is there third possibility, please?

Comment: The third possibility didn't have a title. See the last paragraph! Essentially, boot up your DBH the moment you first need it, and close it, freeing all resources, when your PHP script terminate. This is usually the best way to go.

Comment: @user1800246: excellent, now it is clear. I should avoid Persistent connections if possible. Thanks again.

Comment: Despite all the great answers here, this answer seems to me as the most complete, most detailed, and most explanatory. I have therefore decided, to mark this one as the *Accepted Answer* to my question.

Answer (score 2):

You should always connect database when you **have to**. Imagine google or another bots are visiting your application a lot in a couple of seconds. May be there will be some times that all of your content will be delivered from your cache system.

Moreover, re-opening database connection will cost you directly with waiting your user and consuming more memory because of context switching. You should connect database when you need and you dont have to close it because when your script execution ended your database connection will automatically end up.

Comment: +1: in other words, I should have avoid using persisting connections. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect to database at page load.

To minimize connection time overhead, use [persistent connections.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass,
    array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
?>
```

Comment: hi and +1. if I understand correctly, normally, I should use non-persistent connections at page load. Only when non-persistent connections for some reasons, then I should use persistent connections.

Comment: in practice, it is always better to use persistent connections. It is possible that you may want to disconnect after page processing, but it is not common - simply because another client visiting this page will have to reconnect once again

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opening persistent connection (do you?), then the connection is closed when the script ends (i.e. for every single page) automatically.

And, the execution of opening a connection does not consume resources (well OK, it does, but for a very little time). Maintaining an open connection does.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. +1, if I understand correctly, I shoudl prefer non-persistent connections, as they consume less resources and are easier to handle. Thank you.

Comment: Well, using persistent connection is ideal. But the world isn't. Say every persistent connection needs 1B of memory. If you have 1000 users at the same time, it means 1KB of memory only for the connections. If there are 100 000 it is a 100 KB. If it there are 1 000 000 users, it is 1MB. That is if it needs only 1B, and only the connection identifier takes 0.5B of memory.

Comment: that is great explanation. Now I understand it better. I wish having 1 000 000 users connected at the same time. thank you.